# How to retrieve creation date of an IShellItem?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-shell

I have the pidl of a folder (that may exist or have been deleted).

I can get an `IShellItem` with the following code, but what I need is to get the **Creation date** of that folder. I presume I can get it with `PKEY_DateCreated`, but I don't know how.

```
SHCreateShellItem(nil, nil, pidl, ShellItem);
```

How do I do this ?

I use Delphi.

Comment: This is not a Delphi question. This is a pure COM shell question.

Comment: Do you bind `IShellItem` to `IShellFolder2`? Or do you bind to PIDLs?

Comment: After investigation, I changed the question

Comment: How can you expect to get any information if the folder has been deleted?

Comment: Do shell items have creation dates? Or is that just file system objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a PIDL you can use **[SHGetDataFromIDList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetdatafromidlistw)** to get the basic attributes of the object; you don't need `IShellItem` (or `IShellItem2`) at all. You would specify **SHGDFIL_FINDDATA** for the *nFormat* parameter (see [**SHGetDataFromIDList**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762174(v=vs.85).aspx)
 for details).

The nice thing about this is that for standard filesystem objects the metadata is encoded in the PIDL itself so the function will return useful data even if the object no longer exists.

Comment: It seems nice but I only have an absolute pidl while SHGetDataFromIDList  needs an IShellFolder and relative pidl. Maybe I can get them but how ?

Comment: See the `SHBindToParent` function. You can also try passing the absolute using the desktop folder as its parent (which you get via `SHGetDesktopFolder`) as I've found this often works even if it's not supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

Pure Winapi Example:

```
IShellItem2* pItem2 = NULL;
hr = pItem->QueryInterface(&pItem2);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
   FILETIME ft = {0};
   pItem2->GetFileTime(PKEY_DateCreated, &ft);
   SYSTEMTIME st = {0};
   ::FileTimeToSystemTime(&ft, &st);
   wprintf(
       L"Date Created: %04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", 
       st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay, st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond);
   pItem2->Release();
}
```

Also as David Heffernan pointed, you are sure, that **ALL** shell items have creation dates?

Translated into Delphi that's going to look something like this:

```
var
  Item: IShellItem;
  Item2: IShellItem2;
  ft: TFileTime;
  st: TSystemTime;
....
Item2 := Item as IShellItem2;
OleCheck(Item2.GetFileTime(PKEY_DateCreated, ft));
Win32Check(FileTimeToSystemTime(ft, st));
```

Comment: Nice but it doesn't work under XP bacause of IShellItem2. Any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

### Getting the Creation date

**Using IShellItem2**

`IShellItem2` extends `IShellItem` by added a number of helper methods to retrieve typed properties from the Property System.

```
var
   ft: FILETIME;
   createdDate: TDateTime;

// IShellItem2 provides many handy helper methods to IShellItem
(shellItem as IShellItem2).GetFileTime(PKEY_DateCreated, {out}ft);

createdDate := FileTimeToDateTime(ft);
```

**Using IShellItem**

<strike>Windows Vista</strike> Windows XP<sup>[1](https://archive.fo/gprsT)</sup> added `IShellItem` that wraps up `[IShellFolder]`+`[ITEMID_CHILD]` into a single object. Windows Vista added the rich system of properties, and an `IPropertyStore` is a set of key-value pairs of properties (including `PKEY_DateCreated`):

```
var
   ps: IPropertyStore;
   pv: TPropVariant;
   ft: FILETIME;
   createdDate: TDateTime;

//Get the IPropertyStore yourself, in order to read the property you want
shellItem.BindToHandler(nil, BHID_PropertyStore, IPropertyStore, {out}ps);
ps.GetValue(PKEY_DateCreated, {out}pv);  
PropVariantToFileTime(pv, PSTF_UTC, {out}ft);

createdDate := FileTimeToDateTime(ft);
```

**Using IShellFolder**

`IShellFolder` is the original Windows 95 interface. It represents only a folder, and you have to ask about items (`ITEMID_CHILD`) in that folder. There was no `PKEY_DateCreated` before Vista, because the property system didn't exist *until* Vista. But files and folders still did have a **CreationTime**

```
var
   folder: IShellFolder;
   parent: PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE;
   child: PITEMID_CHILD;
   findData: WIN32_FIND_DATA;

// We have an IShellItem that represents IShellFolder+ChildItemID. 
// Ask the IShellItem to cough up its IShellFolder and child pidl
(shellItem as IParentAndItem).GetParentAndItem(parent, folder, child);

// Get the WIN32_FIND_DATA information associated with the child file/folder
SHGetDataFromIDList(folder, child, SHGDFIL_FINDDATA, findData, sizeof(findData));

createdDate := FileTimeToDateTime(findData.ftCreationTime);
```

Comment: While IShellItem was technically was added in XP SP0 for the Explorer sidebar, it was not usable by 3rd-party code until SP1 or SP2.